# Passbook APN certificate failing (Java/Groovy)

Tags: java, groovy, notifications, push, passbook

I'm trying to write a service in Grails to send push notifications to update passbook passes.  I got to the point where I could test to see if the code to connect to the APN server was working, however, I cannot seem to establish a connection using the Java SSLSocket methods.

The first part of the connection works, I receive the certificate from the server and find a trusted certificate in the certificate chain; however, after that, for some reason my client certificate / certificate chain is not ever sent to the server, and hence the connection fails.

I can't seem to figure out why the certificate is not being sent, I use the following code to set up the keystore:

```
void setupSSLPropertiesForConnection() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "superSecretFile.p12")
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "superSecretPassword")
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12")

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "trustStoreFile")
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "trustStorePassword")
    System.setProperty("javax.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol")
}
```

and then to try and connect to the APN server:

```
setupSSLPropertiesForConnection()
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("gateway.push.apple.com", 2195)
```

I've looked at the PKCS12 file using Java's keytool and there is only one alias, which contains the entire certificate chain for my passbook certificate (certificate, WWDR, Apple Certificate), so I'm stuck on why the certificate isn't being sent when it's requested.  Any help as to why it's not sending the certificate information would be muchly appreciated!

**Edit:** Also, if someone were to post a method of getting a SSL certificate from a .p12 used to sign passes or simply from the passbook certificate downloaded from the iOS dev portal, that is known to work, then I might be able to work backwards from that to figure out what it is I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel silly, apparently the filenames for my client PKCS12 file and the trust store file were both wrong, but in setting the keystore and truststore using the System.setProperty, it doesn't throw any error if the files cannot be found or opened.

I tried changing my code so that I am creating SSLSocketFactory from an SSLContext created with a TrustManagerFactory and a KeyManagerFactory, and when I tried that it threw FileNotFoundError.  Now it seems to be working at least.  Sigh.